# Sitecore page editor render as HTML

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

I have a Sitecore item ("Content Item"), which has a rich text as `"<h2>Header text</h2>"`.

I want this to be rendered as html.

But using a field renderer when I try

```
FieldRenderer1.Item = DatabaseManager.MasterDatabase.GetItem(//content item);
FieldRenderer1.FieldName = "Content";"
```

Text is rendered as `"<h2>Header text</h2>"` in the mark up. How do I get them render as HTML?

Comment: Hello, normally it must work as expected. Can you check if you have checked Raw Valuee field on View Tab on Context Menu from Content Editor ?

Comment: It's turned off, Raw value is "<p>&lt;h2&gt;Be a Smart Seller&lt;/h2&gt;</p>
<p> </p>"

Comment: Agree with sc climber on this.  This is the normal way to use a field renderer.  Ensure that you've added the HTML in the "HTML" view of the RichText editor and not the "Design" view.

Comment: <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer1" runat="server" />

Comment: Yup, HTML is in the "HTML" view. Tried a Multiline text box, it worked. Still wondering why "Richtextbox" does not get rendered as html.

Comment: Any chance you're using your own 'GetFieldValue' processor (in the renderField pipeline), or created anything within the loadRichContent or saveRichContent pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, I think may be trying this might work.

```
<sc:FieldRenderer id="HeaderText" runat="server" FieldName="HeaderText" />
```

This fixed my issues when I was trying something similar at my end.

FieldName specification is a must when it comes to FieldRenderers.